# Could not (help) but

Tags: grammar

I was wondering the structure of “**could not help but**” and the difference between “**could not help**” in this statement:

> “If they wanted to justify their actions, they put forward such boring reasons that they **could not help but** be true.”

Comment: the *reasons* are what are "being true", not the speaker. And since reasons don't make decisions, saying they "couldn't help" doing something is not idiomatic at all

Comment: What do you expect/want this sentence to mean? right now it makes minimal sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but I want the structure of it; in the case that has “but” and in the other one that has not “but”

Comment: *what* do you want the sentence to *mean*? right now it is just words with no meaning

Comment: It’s the statement of the book, it’s not mine

Comment: what book is it from, then? And I assume the (speaker) part was added by you?

Comment: “Word” from “Sartre”, and yes, “speaker” is added by me

Comment: That book is a translation from French, which translation are you reading?

Comment: In this sentence, "they" refers to the *reasons*. The writer is saying that the reasons were so boring, they couldn't possibly have been made up.

Comment: Yes exactly, the translator is “Irene Clephane”

Comment: I’ve got you, you are right :) I meant their reasons, that was my typo, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Could not help" means "Was unable to assist".

"Could not help but" is an idiom that means "Was unable to do anything else except for."

The sentence you quoted means that the *reasons* "they" were giving were so boring that there was no way they could possibly be false. Using this particular idiom isn't common for non-animate beings, because they can't really do anything on their own, but it's a figure of speech that is used here to "personify" the reasons a bit.

You can *not* remove the "but" in this sentence, because then you would lose the idiom altogether, and it would literally mean "could not assist." Since "help" in that context requires an object, it would make no sense *and* not be grammatically correct. (An implied object is ok, like in "I couldn't help" in the context about talking about some event that needs help, but there isn't anything that clearly needs help here, so that doesn't work).

Comment: Thank you so much for your succinct explanation